# Partial View Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a view with DropDown List, on change of this dropdown list i get the id and fill partial view using Jquery Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Edit/Fill',
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: { ID: ID },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Par').html(data);
                },
```

I have a button in my partial view, that saves my data, i want to return to the same page after saving.

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Index(FormCollection All)
    {
    //My Code

    Return PartialView();
 }
```

i also tried to return the same partial view, didn't work??
i want to stay in the same page after the button submit in the Partial view

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is your controller returning the Partial Properly? Is the Jquery not inserting it right?  Are you getting a server error in your controller?

Comment: every thing is running but i want to return to the same page after saving the data

Comment: So you want to just reload the **entire** page on success, not just your div?

Comment: Yes, this what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax method points to `/Edit/Fill`, yet your action method is named `Index`. Don't you mean `/Edit/Index`? The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: No the Edit Field is for the dropdownlist, but the edit index is for the partial view

Comment: Your ajax method **must go to the URL** /Edit/Index in order to hit the action you posted, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: the ajax is fine, all i want is to stay in the same page with the partial view after saving my data.

Comment: Change your action method to return an `ActionResult` and not a `PartialViewResult`, does that fix it? What exactly is the error?

Comment: i did it, put it redirect me to a page that have only the dropdownlist with no style or anything.

Comment: Please ask my anything you want so i can help you to understand because i want to get it to work

Comment: If you want to reload the **entire** page why don't you just submit the form instead of using an AJAX request?

Comment: the ajax request is for the dropdownlist, i'm talking about the button submit in the partial view

Comment: So you want the submit button to just return the page? Or is it the submit button that fires the ajax? If so, you'll need to put a `return false` after your AJAX request.

Comment: To return the partial view or the **entire page**? If so, just `return View` in your post method of your submit button to return the parent view?

Comment: it worked, but is there i way that i can reload the partial view again.

Comment: It should be re-rendered, isn't the partial view on the parent page? Reloading the parent page will reload the partial view.

Comment: no i call the partial view using ajax, so there is no @html.partial()
in my view

Comment: And what exactly fires the AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

- Option1 : if your partial view is not complex view, avoid returning partial view... instead try to return json data from your Ajax call, and bind the json data to parent view using Jquery.
- Option2: When you hit save, instead of form submit try to use Ajax call to save your data.
- Option 3: a form submit requires the page to reload, so on page load collect drop-down id and do your Ajax call to load your partial view. (you might have to use session data to load right values in your partial view)